# How to play audio in simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    @IBAction func keyPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        playSound(soundName: sender.currentTitle!)
        
    }
    
    func playSound(soundName: String) {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundName, withExtension: "wav")
        let player = AVPlayer.init(url: url!)
        player.play()
        print(url!)
    }

}
```

file:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C3333006-1A90-4B12-A9F6-E04B3603334C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/265FB456-9524-44DY-B669-D67ACB7F444C/Xylophone.app/D.wav

I'm trying to play sound, which are already in the package folder, but failed to do so in simulator, can't play any sound even if unmute and increase sound volume of the simulator and my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and it works:

```
let jingleURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "jingle", ofType: ".mp3")!)
let jingleAVPlayer = AVPlayer.init(url: jingleURL)

jingleAVPlayer.play()
```

The filename is jingle.mp3 and is added in Xcode.

I hope this helps you out ;)